# Sharepoint hosted web application - custom security

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need to implement a web application hosted on sharepoint. This is a client requirement. So I cannot create a standard asp.net web application. Another client requirement is that the authentication is not an active directory one but they want to use an existing database of users.

I am a bit concerned how this would work on sharepoint because users would need to log-in onto sharepoint. Would it make sense that users log into sharepoint as anonymous and then we use our custom controls for log-in. How does sharepoint handle anonymous users?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you ever build apps on SharePoint ? I hope the answer is yes... because entering the SharePoint world can be painful. It takes month before being a good SharePoint developer. Fortunately, SharePoint can provides a great platform, when the initial learning hill is climbed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building apps over SharePoint, you use the SharePoint authentication mechanism, whatever it is.

Does the SharePoint farm is already in place ? Or do you have to also build the farm ?

In the former case, probably the authentication mechanism is already in place and you just have to build a "standard" sharepoint application.

In the later case, you will have to carefully plan your authentication. SharePoint can use a combination of AD authentication, Forms authentication (over a DB in your case if you want) or a Claims authentication pattern. My guess is that a Forms authentication with a custom Membership/role provider is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sharepoint farm has to be built. Your option for a custom Membership provider makes a lot of sense. Many thanks.